# pom.xml error in maven project using eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, jstl, pom.xml

I am making a maven project in eclipse for CRUD operations and whenever I am adding jstl dependency version 1.2 the pom.xml is showing error even though the jstl dependency get downloaded and also the tomact server doesn't work in this case but when I am removing the JSTL dependency the pom file is not showing error.  Can somebody tell me how it is happening

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment So I will try to answer without having the full context. It will be great if you can paste your pom.xml file.

Anyway,

> The pom.xml is showing error

A possible error can be the format of the pom.xml. I believe you are disturbing the format.

> Tomcat is not working after that.

Please check the dependency graph in both the case for the Tomcat. You will resolve it by yourself then.

PS. It will be great if you can post you pom.xml file.